# C# Updating Database after edited inputs using DataBindings

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf

I'm using WCF Service and Windows Form.
My problem is how to code the Update button after editing the text fields.
In my windows form, I have this code:

```
            ServiceReference1.StockCardServicesClient sList = new ServiceReference1.StockCardServicesClient();
            BindingSource StockCardList = new BindingSource();

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                StockCardList.DataSource = sList.GetParticularCard();
txtID.DataBindings.Add(new Binding("Text", StockCardList, "CategoryName", true));
            txtOPCOID.DataBindings.Add(new Binding("Text", StockCardList, "MainGroupName", true));
            txtSubGroupID.DataBindings.Add(new Binding("Text", StockCardList, "SubGroupName", true));
            txtIDNumber.DataBindings.Add(new Binding("Text", StockCardList, "IDNumber", true));
            txtPartNumber.DataBindings.Add(new Binding("Text", StockCardList, "PartNumber", true));
            txtDescription.DataBindings.Add(new Binding("Text", StockCardList, "Description", true));
            }
```

and after editing the textbox content, I want to update using Update Button.

```
    private void btnUpdate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
ServiceReference1.StockCardServicesClient sList = new ServiceReference1.StockCardServicesClient();
                ServiceReference1.StockList stockDetails = new ServiceReference1.StockList();
                StockCardList.EndEdit();

                sList.UpdateStockCard(stockDetails)
    }
```

Here are the codes of my WCF Service DAL

```
public void UpdateStockCard(StockList stockDetails)
{
    con.Open();
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("UPDATE StockCard SET PartNumber=@partNumber WHERE IDNumber='1731-000246'", con);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@categoryName", stockDetails.CategoryName);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@mainGroupName", stockDetails.MainGroupName);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@subGroupName", stockDetails.SubGroupName);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@idNumber", stockDetails.IDNumber);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@partNumber", stockDetails.PartNumber);
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    con.Close();
}
```

In my BLL and ENT is working fine.

Thank you

Comment: It looks like you are trying to bind and edit a collection of items with one set of textboxes. You should be binding to a control like a grid or use a Binding Navigator.

Comment: I'm not using datagridview in that windows form. All details should be in the textbox to edit. And it should be updated using the Update button.

Comment: I just noticed the call to GetParticularCard. I guess this obtains a single item. So, now I would ask - what is the problem you are having?

Comment: I want to update records in my database after I edit the textbox fields. As you can see, I have a btnUpdate_Click to update, but I don't know how to code.

Comment: I think using a BindingSource is a bit overkill here since you are editing only one item and crossing system boundries so you cannot make use of built in update features, but I could write an answer if I knew what type `GetParticularCard()` returned.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, there are 22 fields or text boxes to update. I show only that code for a sample. But if I will write this code below, it will work.

```
private void btnUpdate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
                ServiceReference1.StockList stockDetails = new ServiceReference1.StockList();

            stockDetails.CategoryName = txtID.Text;
            stockDetails.MainGroupName = txtOPCOID.Text;
            stockDetails.SubGroupName = txtSubGroupID.Text;
            stockDetails.IDNumber = txtIDNumber.Text;
            stockDetails.PartNumber = txtPartNumber.Text;

                sList.UpdateStockCard(stockDetails);
}
```

and I know there is a better way to update the records from data bindings but I don't know how to code it.

Answer (score 0):

I already figured it out. Here is my code.

```
public partial class frmStockList : Form
{
    ServiceReference1.StockCardServicesClient stockList = new ServiceReference1.StockCardServicesClient();
    ServiceReference1.StockList stockDetails = new ServiceReference1.StockList();

    public frmStockList(frmMainForm mainForm)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ShowStockListDetails();
    }

    private void ShowStockListDetails()
    {
        stockDetails.SearchIDNumber = frmMainForm.stockCardID.ToString();

        var StockList = stockList.GetParticularCard(stockDetails);

        stockDetails = StockList[0];

        BindingSource StockCardList = new BindingSource();

        StockCardList.ResetBindings(false);

        StockCardList.DataSource = stockDetails;

        txtID.DataBindings.Add(new Binding("Text", StockCardList, "CategoryName", true));
        txtOPCOID.DataBindings.Add(new Binding("Text", StockCardList, "MainGroupName", true));
        txtSubGroupID.DataBindings.Add(new Binding("Text", StockCardList, "SubGroupName", true));
        txtIDNumber.DataBindings.Add(new Binding("Text", StockCardList, "IDNumber", true));
        txtPartNumber.DataBindings.Add(new Binding("Text", StockCardList, "PartNumber", true));
        txtDescription.DataBindings.Add(new Binding("Text", StockCardList, "Description", true));
        txtMinimum.DataBindings.Add(new Binding("Text", StockCardList, "Minimum", true));
        txtMaximum.DataBindings.Add(new Binding("Text", StockCardList, "Maximum", true));
        cmbUOMPO.DataBindings.Add(new Binding("Text", StockCardList, "UOMPO", true));
        cmbUOMSTOCK.DataBindings.Add(new Binding("Text", StockCardList, "UOMStock", true));
        cmbUOMPERISSUE.DataBindings.Add(new Binding("Text", StockCardList, "UOMIssue", true));
        txtUOMRatio.DataBindings.Add(new Binding("Text", StockCardList, "UOMRatio", true));
        txtWidth.DataBindings.Add(new Binding("Text", StockCardList, "Width", true));
        txtHeight.DataBindings.Add(new Binding("Text", StockCardList, "Height", true));
        txtLength.DataBindings.Add(new Binding("Text", StockCardList, "Length", true));
        txtNetWeight.DataBindings.Add(new Binding("Text", StockCardList, "NetWeight", true));
        txtWarningExpiration.DataBindings.Add(new Binding("Text", StockCardList, "WarningPeriod", true));
        txtShelfLife.DataBindings.Add(new Binding("Text", StockCardList, "ShelfLife", true));
        txtCostCode.DataBindings.Add(new Binding("Text", StockCardList, "CostCodePurchase", true));
        cmbIssueToJob.DataBindings.Add(new Binding("Text", StockCardList, "CostCodeIssueToJob", true));
        cmbIssueToWS.DataBindings.Add(new Binding("Text", StockCardList, "CostCodeIssueToWS", true));
        cmbIssueToOPCO.DataBindings.Add(new Binding("Text", StockCardList, "CostCodeIssueToOPCO", true));
        cmbIssueForDisposalSCD.DataBindings.Add(new Binding("Text", StockCardList, "CostCodeIssueToDisposalSCD", true));
        cmbIssueForDisposalDMG.DataBindings.Add(new Binding("Text", StockCardList, "CostCodeIssueToDisposalDMG", true));
        cmbIssueForDisposalEXP.DataBindings.Add(new Binding("Text", StockCardList, "CostCodeIssueToDisposalEXP", true));
        cmbIssueForDisposalOBS.DataBindings.Add(new Binding("Text", StockCardList, "CostCodeIssueToDisposalOBS", true));
    }
    private void btnClose_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Close();
        Dispose();
    }

    private void btnUpdate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        stockDetails.ID = frmMainForm.stockCardID.ToString();

        stockList.UpdateStockCard(stockDetails);

        MessageBox.Show("Update successfull!", "Update Details", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
        Close();
        Dispose();
    }
}
```