# C# DataBindings - two bindings to same property error

Tags: c#, winforms, data-binding, datasource

I don't know if my question is correct. What I mean is after saving the edited fields from DataBindings, after updating the database, I want to reload the data. After Reloading or calling the `ShowStockListDetails();`, I will get this error `**System.ArgumentException:** 'This causes two bindings in the collection to bind to the same property. Parameter name: binding'`

Bellow is my code:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    ServiceReference1.StockCardServicesClient sList = new ServiceReference1.StockCardServicesClient();
    BindingSource StockCardList = new BindingSource();

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ShowStockListDetails();
    }

    private void ShowStockListDetails()
    {
        StockCardList.DataSource = sList.GetParticularCard();

        txtPartNumber.DataBindings.Add(new Binding("Text", StockCardList, "PartNumber", true));
        txtDescription.DataBindings.Add(new Binding("Text", StockCardList, "Description", true));
        txtMinimum.DataBindings.Add(new Binding("Text", StockCardList, "Minimum", true));
        txtMaximum.DataBindings.Add(new Binding("Text", StockCardList, "Maximum", true));
        cmbUOMPO.DataBindings.Add(new Binding("Text", StockCardList, "UOMPO", true));
        cmbUOMSTOCK.DataBindings.Add(new Binding("Text", StockCardList, "UOMStock", true));
        cmbUOMPERISSUE.DataBindings.Add(new Binding("Text", StockCardList, "UOMIssue", true));
    }

    private void btnClose_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Close();
        Dispose();
    }

    private void btnUpdate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        ServiceReference1.StockList stockDetails = new ServiceReference1.StockList();

        stockDetails.PartNumber = txtPartNumber.Text;
        stockDetails.Description = txtDescription.Text;
        stockDetails.Minimum = txtMinimum.Text;
        stockDetails.Maximum = txtMaximum.Text;
        stockDetails.UOMPO = cmbUOMPO.Text;
        stockDetails.UOMStock = cmbUOMSTOCK.Text;
        stockDetails.UOMIssue = cmbUOMPERISSUE.Text;

        sList.UpdateStockCard(stockDetails); // Calling WCF Service DAL

        ShowStockListDetails(); // Reload DataSource and Bind

        MessageBox.Show("Update successfull!", "Update Details", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi @DaniDev I will refer you to this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48380443/c-sharp-updating-database-after-edited-inputs-using-databindings[link] 
The code of my btnUpdate now is temporary. I think that this is not a perfect way to save/update data from databindings.

Comment: sorry i couldnt help. when you add databindings, you dont need to reset the bindings. you do that once, and just update the objects the bindings are attached to. that should help you figure it out. since this is a webpage, you might need to to reattach the bindings once every time you do a callback. have you tried to remove the binding in the load event?

Comment: I think you are right @Heriberto. What I will do now is close the form after updating and open again from the datagridview.
Even I will remove from load event still there is an error.